# GnuPG "public key decryption failed: Invalid ID" using Yubikey Smartcard

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, yubikey

I'm trying to decrypt a file that was signed with my ssb key stored on my Yubikey, but I get the following errors:

```
x>gpg -vv --decrypt encrypted.gpg
gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP MESSAGE
# off=0 ctb=XX tag=1 hlen=3 plen=XXX
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid XXXX5753679AAAAA
        data: [4096 bits]
gpg: public key is XXXX5753679AAAAA
# off=XXX ctb=XX tag=1 hlen=3 plen=XXX
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid XXXX05D83EFAAAAA
        data: [4096 bits]
gpg: public key is XXXX05D83EFAAAAA
gpg: using subkey XXXX05D83EFAAAAA instead of primary key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
# off=XXXX ctb=XX tag=XX hlen=2 plen=0 partial new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
        length: unknown
        mdc_method: 2
gpg: using subkey XXXX05D83EFAAAAA instead of primary key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID XXXX05D83EFAAAAA, created 2018-XX-XX
      "x (Personal Key) <x@gmail.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Invalid ID
gpg: using subkey XXXX5753679AAAAA instead of primary key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID XXXX5753679AAAAA, created 2018-XX-XX
      "y <y@gmail.com>"
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

To make sure my smartcard was being detected, I ran gpg --card-status, which worked, and I saw the same ID in the output. Anyone know why I can't decrypt using my yubikey? Thanks.

Also, I ran gpg --list-secret-keys:

```
x>gpg --list-secret-keys
C:/Users/x/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/pubring.kbx
--------------------------------------------------
sec>  rsa4096 2018-xx-xx [SC] [expires: 2019-xx-xx]
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      Card serial no. = 000X 0XXXXXXX
uid           [ultimate] x (Personal Key) <x@gmail.com>
ssb>  rsa4096 2018-xx-xx [E] [expires: 2019-xx-xx]
ssb>  rsa4096 2018-xx-xx [SEA] [expires: 2019-xx-xx]
```

The thing is, I don't have the second secret key, only the first. The issue seems to be "public key decryption failed: Invalid ID" (the secret key of this public key is on my smartcard).

Comment: Can you provide the verion of GnuPG that you're working? Also, check [this](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2015-September/054312.html) discussion that's pretty similar.

Comment: @MikeM. gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.10
libgcrypt 1.8.3

Comment: @MikeM. Also, before posting I researched a ton and found a few references, but no solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really reproduce the problem without the specific product. Did you check [this](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/faq/missing-keys-after-migrating-to-gnupg-22#yubikey-no-longer-working)? It's the most relevant information I can find.

Comment: Have you successfully decrypted a file using this particular Yubikey/computer before? I once had an issue that arose from key handles pointing to my backup smartcard when I tried using my primary. ```--card-status``` looked fine but the key handle wouldn't update until I deleted it outright and checked the card again.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem today. I still have no idea what causes it, but I can reproduce it every time. I have gotten it to work consistently by doing the following:

1. plug in the yubikey
2. run `gpg --card-edit`
3. at the prompt type "verify" (and enter the password to unlock the card)
4. Quit out of gpg card edit, and then I am able to decrypt files as normal.

I am still looking for a less manual solution but this has been working for now.

Comment: i switched off forced Signature PIN in: gpg --edit-card -> admin -> forcesig.
This seems to be the issue somehow.